# Accsess S3 from the command line without a secret key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some files on a S3 account that I don’t own and therefore do not have the secret key for. Using a link that was sent to me, I can enter the “Account Number”, user name and password I can login to the s3 console and download the files I need from various buckets.

When trying to configure `s3cmd` or the AWS CLI tools however, both require that I enter the AWS access key as well as my secret key, which I don’t have. I find it strange that I can access the files through a web browser without the secret key, yet can’t do the same from the command line.

Is there a way to download files from S3 using a command line, without having access to the secret key? If so, how do I properly configure either `s3cmd` or the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

When you download via the console, the console infrastructure obtains a temporary key, secret, and token on your behalf to allow the downloads. (And no, you can't access this information.  The key and the token are embedded in the download link, but not the secret).

Whoever gave you the account needs to also give you a key and a secret so you can access these resources.  Or, if you have permission to do so, you can go into "IAM" in the console and create a set.

Answer (score 1):

If the owner was to provide a [pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for each file you could use curl to download from the command line.